# DJANGO - SQLServer - Error al conectar a la base de datos

Tags: sql-server, django

Al intentar establecer una conexión con Django a SQLServer, me devuelve el siguiente error:
¿Qué sucede?

**django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Proveedor de TCP: No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión.\r\n (10061) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Ha finalizado el tiempo de espera de inicio de sesión (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Atributo de cadena de conexión no válido (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Error relacionado con la red o específico de instancia al establecer conexión con el servidor SQL Server. El servidor no se encuentra o no está accesible. Compruebe si el nombre de la instancia es correcto y si SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexiones remotas. Para obtener más información, vea los Libros en pantalla de SQL Server. (10061)')**

Datos de conexión:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': "sql_server.pyodbc",
        'HOST': "127.0.0.1,22076",
        'USER': "usr_almacen",
        'PASSWORD': "12341234",
        'NAME': "almacen",
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

Datos de conexión2 (doble comilla a "ODBC..."):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': "sql_server.pyodbc",
        'HOST': "DESKTOP-SA69OQB,22076",
        'USER': "usr_almacen",
        'PASSWORD': "34123412",
        'NAME': "almacen",
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
        },
    }
}
```

Aplicacion instalada:

**pip install django-pyodbc-azure**

Supongo que el puerto utilizado es el que marca como PID

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Instalaste `pyodbc`? (`pip install pyodbc`)

Comment: Sí, ya instalé pyodbc sí. Y no he conseguido conectar con SQLServer. He intentado de todas las maneras que se me han ocurrido, pero me devuelve error. Lo he intentado incluso con SQLServer Developer y SQLServer Express (son gratuitos), pero de momento nada. Algo haré mal, pero no doy con el error. Gracias Julio Cesar.

Comment: Julian, tratando de investigar sobre el problema, me encontré con [este](https://medium.com/@royce236/django-and-ms-sql-server-2012-connection-2018-120c54dfc037) articulo, para conectar Django con SQL Server, en dicho articulo se menciona que puede dar errores utilizar comillas simples (específicamente: `'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'`) por la función de análisis de cadenas de la biblioteca **pyodbc**, intenta cambiándolo a comillas dobles a ver si se soluciona. Y revisa dicho articulo que da posibles soluciones a posibles errores.

Comment: PID es proces ID, el puerto se puede dejar en blanco o indicar el de SQL server que es el 1433